# Launching App in landscape mode after ios 2.1

Tags: ios, uiview

Im wondering what am i missing from following the steps apple tells me to follow [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW9) under the submenu Displaying App In landscape mode. What is happening is my coordinate system is all messed up, the only instruction of of the 3 i dont beleive i entirely figured out is
Lay out your views in landscape mode and make sure that their layout or autosizing options are set correctly.
and this is the reason why i believe that my coordinate system is all messed up. To solve this i found some code online that fixes my coordinate space for me but that way of solving this is only needed for ios 2.1 and below. So can someone tell me what i need to do in order not to use that code?

Comment: iOS 2.1? Really? At this point in time there is little need to support anything before iOS 5.0.

Comment: Im only supporting ios 5.0 and above but what apple tells me to do in the link i posted doesnt work. How they used to solve this problem in ios 2.1 and below is they would flip the coordinate space of each view. Im trying to figure out what i am missing from apples instructions....

Comment: in order to not use the flip the coordinate space code

Comment: for more information go to this page http://iphonedevsdk.com/discussion/comment/465932#Comment_465932